# Can't detach child process when main process is started from systemd

Tags: linux, go, process, systemd

I want to spawn long-running child processes that survive when the main process restarts/dies. This works fine when running from the terminal:

```
$ cat exectest.go
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
        "syscall"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        if len(os.Args) == 2 && os.Args[1] == "child" {
                for {   
                        time.Sleep(time.Second)
                }
        } else {
                cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], "child")
                cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setsid: true}
                log.Printf("child exited: %v", cmd.Run())
        }
}
$ go build
$ ./exectest
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./exectest
$ bg
[1]+ ./exectest &
$ ps -ef | grep exectest | grep -v grep | grep -v vim
snowm     7914  5650  0 23:44 pts/7    00:00:00 ./exectest
snowm     7916  7914  0 23:44 ?        00:00:00 ./exectest child
$ kill -INT 7914 # kill parent process
[1]+  Exit 2                  ./exectest
$ ps -ef | grep exectest | grep -v grep | grep -v vim
snowm     7916     1  0 23:44 ?        00:00:00 ./exectest child
```

Note that the child process is still alive after parent process was killed. However, if I start the main process from systemd like this...

```
[snowm@localhost exectest]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/exectest.service 
[Unit]
Description=ExecTest

[Service]                        
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/snowm/src/exectest/exectest
User=snowm

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
$ sudo systemctl enable exectest
ln -s '/etc/systemd/system/exectest.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/exectest.service'
$ sudo systemctl start exectest
```

... then the child also dies when I kill the main process:

```
$ ps -ef | grep exectest | grep -v grep | grep -v vim
snowm     8132     1  0 23:55 ?        00:00:00 /home/snowm/src/exectest/exectest
snowm     8134  8132  0 23:55 ?        00:00:00 /home/snowm/src/exectest/exectest child
$ kill -INT 8132
$ ps -ef | grep exectest | grep -v grep | grep -v vim
$
```

How can I make the child survive?

Running go version go1.4.2 linux/amd64 under CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core).

Comment: SystemD probably kills everything in the process group (or cgroup, I haven't looked at the systemd setup in a while). Are you actually trying to emulate daemon behavior, or is this just for an example?

Comment: @JimB: My actual code spawns child processes that run ffmpeg. I'm basically using the pattern above to emulate daemon behavior, yes.

Comment: Why not leave the parent running, and let systemd manage it normally? I think there might be a way to spawn the child and notify system of the new process, but the former would be much easier.

Comment: @JimB: The child processes are expensive to restart, so they must not die when main process is restarted or crashes. However, thanks to your cgroup hint I found that the solution is to say `KillMode=process` (defaults to  `control-group`).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solution is to add

```
KillMode=process
```

to the service block. Default value is `control-group` which means systemd cleans up any child processes.

From [man systemd.kill](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html)

> KillMode= Specifies how processes of this unit shall be killed. One of
>   control-group, process, mixed, none.
>
> If set to control-group, all remaining processes in the control group
>   of this unit will be killed on unit stop (for services: after the stop
>   command is executed, as configured with ExecStop=). If set to process,
>   only the main process itself is killed. If set to mixed, the SIGTERM
>   signal (see below) is sent to the main process while the subsequent
>   SIGKILL signal (see below) is sent to all remaining processes of the
>   unit's control group. If set to none, no process is killed. In this
>   case, only the stop command will be executed on unit stop, but no
>   process be killed otherwise. Processes remaining alive after stop are
>   left in their control group and the control group continues to exist
>   after stop unless it is empty.

Comment: Would there be a way to move the process out of the group instead?

Comment: This saved me. Thank you.

Comment: Today, the manual tells us that "If set to 'process', only the main process itself is killed **(not recommended!)**". Any idea why this is discouraged?

Answer (score 7):

The only way I know to solve this is to launch the child process with the --scope argument.

```bash
systemd-run --user --scope firefox
```

KillMode has been mentioned here also, but changing the KillMode also means that if your main process crashes, systemd won't restart it if any child process is still running.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me and it's better than the accepted answer (at least for me) because I don't need to change systemd KillMode.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot (like me) to change the `KillMode` of the service for some reason, you could try the `at` command (see [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)).

You can schedule your command to run 1 minute ahead. See an example:

```sh
# this will remove all .tmp files from "/path/" in 1 minute ahead (this task will run once)
echo rm /path/*.tmp | at now + 1 minute
```