# How to launch a process outside a systemd control group

Tags: linux, signals, systemd

I have a server process (launched from systemd) which can launch an update process.  The update process self-daemonizes itself and then (in theory) kills the server with SIGTERM.  My problem is that the SIGTERM propagates to the update process *and it's children*.

For debugging purposes, the update process just sleeps, and I send the kill by hand.

Sample PS output before the kill:

```
    1  1869  1869  1869 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00 /usr/local/bin/state_controller --start
 1869  1873  1869  1869 ?           -1 Sl       0   0:00  \_ ProcessWebController --start
 1869  1886  1869  1869 ?           -1 Z        0   0:00  \_ [UpdateSystem] <defunct>
    1  1900  1900  1900 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/UpdateSystem refork /var/ttm/update.bin
 1900  1905  1900  1900 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ sleep 10000
```

Note that UpdateSystem is in a separate PGID and TPGID.  (The `<defunct>` process is a result of the daemonization, and is not (I think) a problem.)

UpdateSystem is a bash script (although I can easily make it a C program if that will help).  After the daemonization code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29107686/771073, the interesting bit is:

```
#############################################
trap "echo Ignoring SIGTERM" SIGTERM
sleep 10000
echo Awoken from sleep - presumably by the SIGTERM
exit 0
```

When I `kill 1869` (which sends SIGTERM to the `state_controller` server process, my logfile contains:

```
Terminating
Ignoring SIGTERM
Awoken from sleep - presumably by the SIGTERM
```

I really want to prevent SIGTERM being sent to the `sleep` process.

(Actually, I *really* want to stop it being sent to `apt-get upgrade` which is stopping the system via the moral equivalent of `systemctl stop ttm.service` and the `ExecStop` is specified as `/bin/kill $MAINPID` - just in case that changes anyone's answer.)

This question is similar, but the accepted answer (use `KillMode=process`) doesn't work well for me - I want to kill some of the child processes, just not the update process: 
[Can't detach child process when main process is started from systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208782/cant-detach-child-process-when-main-process-is-started-from-systemd)

Answer (score 8):

We were having exactly the same problem. What we ended up doing is launching the update process as [transient cgroup with systemd-run](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-using_control_groups#sec-Creating_Transient_Cgroups_with_systemd-run):

```sh
systemd-run --unit=my_system_upgrade --scope --slice=my_system_upgrade_slice -E  setsid nohup start-the-upgrade &> /tmp/some-logs.log &
```

That way, the update process will run in a different cgroup and will not be terminated. Additionally, we use `setsid` + `nohup` to make sure the process has its own group and session and that the parent process is the init process.

Comment: Solid answer, definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

A completely different approach is for the upgrade process to remove itself from the service group by updating the `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd` filesystem.  Specifically in bash:

```
echo $$ > /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks
```

A process belongs to exactly one control group.  Writing its PID to the root `tasks` file adds it to the *other* control group, and removes it from the service control group.

Comment: Some distros have been switched to _cgroupsv2_ only. These are missing `tasks` file and `cgroup.procs` should be used instead. See https://man.archlinux.org/man/cgroups.7#Creating_cgroups_and_moving_processes

Comment: some distros use 'unified' cgroup. systemd on ubuntu18.04 kill all child process under `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/system.slice/myservice.servie/cgroup.procs`.  This in bash works: `echo $$ > /sys/fs/cgroup/{systemd,unified}/cgroup.procs`

Comment: @seamaner: bash: /sys/fs/cgroup/{systemd,unified}/cgroup.procs: ambiguous redirect

Answer (score 3):

The approach we have decided to take is to launch the update process in a separate (single-shot) service.  As such, it automatically belongs to a separate control group, so killing the main service doesn't kill it.

There is a wrinkle to this though.  The package installs `ttm.service` and `ttm.template.update.service`.  To run the updater, we copy `ttm.template.update.service` to `ttm.update.service`, run `systemctl daemon-reload`, and then run `systemctl start ttm.update.service`.  Why the copy?  Because when the updater installs a new version of `ttm.template.update.service`, it will forcibly terminate any processes running as that service.  `KillMode=None` appears to offer a way round that, but although it appears to work, a subsequent call to apt-get yields a nasty error about dpkg having been interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not systemd sending the TERM signal to the child process?

Depending on the service type, if your main process dies, systemd will do a cleanup and terminate all the child processes under the same cgroup.

This is defined by KillMode= property which is by default set to control-group. You could set it to "none" or "process". https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html

Comment: "I want to kill some of the child processes, just not the update process"

Answer (score 0):

I have same sitation with you.

Upgrade process is a child process of parent process. The parent process is call by a service.

The main point is not Cgroup, is MAINPID.

If you use PIDFILE to sepecify the MAINPID, when the service type = forking, then the situation solved.

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/test.pid
```