# What is the way to avoid systemctl from killing one of my child processes on a stop?

Tags: c++, process, systemd

I have been trying to do an upgrade from within a server by running the simple Debian upgrade command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, if that upgrade includes myself (i.e. say I have a package named **server** and part of the upgrade includes a newer version of **server**,) then the upgrade fails. More precisely, whenever dpkg runs the `preinst` script, the process running the command shown earlier gets killed because it runs `systemctl stop server`.

The code does something like this:

```
// start with systemd
systemctl start server

// the server runs another daemon which manages the computer packages
// this is C++ code within server doing something like:
if(fork() == 0)
{
    execv("package_manager", ...);
}

// if I look at the output of systemctl status server, I see:
systemctl status server
  CGroup: server
          +-- package_manager

// then package_manager decides to do an upgrade, it starts a process
system("do_server_upgrade");

// in the do_server_upgrade code, I use fork() again to leave the
// existing set of daemons (server and package_manager)
int main()
{
    if(fork() != 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    setsid();
    signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
    ...run the commands to apply the upgrades...
}
```

As per [this stackoverflow answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208782/cant-detach-child-process-when-main-process-is-started-from-systemd#32209842) I learned that systemd will kill (send SIGTERM) all the children processes in the same `control-group`.

So I was thinking that was a neat feature for all the other daemons run by server... except for that one `do_server_upgrade`. In other words, I would appreciate to keep it that way (i.e. `KillMode=control-group`) but it does not look like there is a way to get a child process out of that control group.

My question here is: Does someone know about such capability? Can I keep my service set to `control-group` and kick some processes out of that control group?

Comment: No, there's no such capability.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, ah well... too bad. My server already tracks what is running and kills everything anyway, but it would have been nice from `systemd` to let a few escape once in a while (instead of all or nothing...)

Comment: Of course you can get a process out of your control group. Just use a tool like `at` or `cron` to start it, instead of directly starting that process yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask systemd to start a process inside a new control group by using the [systemd-run command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html).