# From within ruby: How do I spawn a process in a different control group than the current?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

Using `Kernel.spawn` I can start a new process from within ruby, executing som arbitrary shell commands. The new process will appear in the same `control group` as the ruby process. How can I change that to have it go in it's own?

The reason for me wanting this is that my ruby process is managed by `systemd` and I don't want any of these particular shell command processes to be cleaned up/terminated when the ruby process is restarted.

Comment: Would `type=forking` work? I'm not sure how that works with multiple forked processes though.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way to do this. Instead I changed the `KillMode` of my systemd script to `process`, this solved the problem: [Can't detach child process when main process is started from systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208782/cant-detach-child-process-when-main-process-is-started-from-systemd#32209842)